# How to list subdirectories from an URL on a HTTP file share?

Tags: http, curl, wget, directory-browsing

I would like to know if there is an easy name to list all files/directories from a HTTP file share - by default the HTTP server displays them but I'm wondering is there is an easy way to get the list of files without manually parsing the returned webpage.

Any solution that would use `curl`, `wget` or `python` should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no generic way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

wget is only designed to download files not list directories.

If that's all you've got, though...

```
wget -r http://SOME.SITE/PATH 2>&1 | grep 'Saving to:' | sed "s/Saving to: \`\([^?']*\).*'/\1/" | uniq -u
rm -rf SOME.SITE
```

(Just so you don't sue me later, this is **downloading all of the files** from the site and **then deleting them** when it's done)

**Edit:** Sorry, I'm tired. If you want *only* the top-level directories, you can do something like this:

```
wget -rq http://SOME.SITE/PATH
ls -1p SOME.SITE | grep '/$'
rm -rf SOME.SITE
```

This does the same as above, but only lists immediate subdirectories of the URL.